How do I center a table inside a div while not losing overflow
I have a dashboard HTML page that has 2 sections:
 for vertical navbar 
 for a table of people (and optionally some h1 text later on)
I just want a way for the table to be centered in main, and when it gets smaller a scrollbar appears for x-overflow.
THE PROBLEM IS: when the table gets bigger than the screen it starts hiding behind nav
Additionally if any of you can help me get the scrollbar to appear on the table body rather than outside the table or on the div that would also be greatly appreciated


:root{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    scrollbar-width: thin;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: black;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

main{
    margin-left: 15rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    overflow-x: auto;
    scrollbar-width: thin;
}

.navbar{
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 15rem;
    background-color: #fafafa;
}

.navbar-nav{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.navbar-item{
    width: 15rem;
    height: 5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.navbar-item:first-child{
    width: 15rem;
    height: 5rem;
}

.navbar-item:first-child img{
    width: 7rem;
    height: auto;
}


.navbar-item:not(:first-child):hover{
    background-color: rgb(222, 221, 221);
}

.navbar-item:not(:first-child):active {
    background-color: #0f9660;
}

.navbar-item:not(:first-child):active>a {
    color: white;
}

.navbar-item:last-child{
    border: none;
    margin-top: auto;
}

.navbar-item:last-child a:hover {
    background-color: #da413e;
    color: white;
}


.nav-link{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar-item svg{
    width: 1rem;
    height: auto;
}

.active{
    background-color: rgb(222, 221, 221);
}
```

dashboard.css

```
.table thead{
    background-color: #0f9660;
    color: white;
}

.div-table{
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.div-table table{
    width: 48rem;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.table th{
    width: 6rem;
    height: 2rem;
    padding: 0 1rem;
}
.table td{
    padding: 0 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.table tr:nth-of-type(even){
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
}

.icons{
    width: auto;
    height: 1rem;
}
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="navbar-item"><img src="../cri.png" alt="Logo of CRI"></li>
            <li class="navbar-item active"><a href="../dashboard/dashboard.html" class="nav-link">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-item"><a href="../search/search.html" class="nav-link">Advanced Search</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-item"><a href="../current/current.html" class="nav-link">Current interns</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-item"><a href="../logs/logs.html" class="nav-link">Read Logs</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Disconnect</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <div class="div-table">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Nom
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Prenom
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            CIN
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Email
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Numero
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Etudiant
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            CV
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Accepter
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Refuser
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Abdelhak</td>
                        <td>Abdelaziz</td>
                        <td>BD2034591</td>
                        <td>abdelazizabde@gmail.com</td>
                        <td>+212672729112</td>
                        <td>Oui</td>
                        <td><a class="file" href=""><img class="icons" src="file.svg" alt="file"></a></td>
                        <td><a class="link-accepted" href=""><img class="icons" src="accepted.svg" alt="accepted"></a></td>
                        <td><a class="link-rejected" href=""><img class="icons" src="rejected.svg" alt="rejected"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Abdelhak</td>
                        <td>Abdelaziz</td>
                        <td>BD2034591</td>
                        <td>abdelazizabde@gmail.com</td>
                        <td>+212672729112</td>
                        <td>Oui</td>
                        <td><a class="file" href=""><img class="icons" src="file.svg" alt="file"></a></td>
                        <td><a class="link-accepted" href=""><img class="icons" src="accepted.svg" alt="accepted"></a></td>
                        <td><a class="link-rejected" href=""><img class="icons" src="rejected.svg" alt="rejected"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Abdelhak</td>
                        <td>Abdelaziz</td>
                        <td>BD2034591</td>
                        <td>abdelazizabde@gmail.com</td>
                        <td>+212672729112</td>
                        <td>Oui</td>
                        <td><a class="file" href=""><img class="icons" src="file.svg" alt="file"></a></td>
                        <td><a class="link-accepted" href=""><img class="icons" src="accepted.svg" alt="accepted"></a></td>
                        <td><a class="link-rejected" href=""><img class="icons" src="rejected.svg" alt="rejected"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Abdelhak</td>
                        <td>Abdelaziz</td>
                        <td>BD2034591</td>
                        <td>abdelazizabde@gmail.com</td>
                        <td>+212672729112</td>
                        <td>Oui</td>
                        <td><a class="file" href=""><img class="icons" src="file.svg" alt="file"></a></td>
                        <td><a class="link-accepted" href=""><img class="icons" src="accepted.svg" alt="accepted"></a></td>
                        <td><a class="link-rejected" href=""><img class="icons" src="rejected.svg" alt="rejected"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Abdelhak</td>
                        <td>Abdelaziz</td>
                        <td>BD2034591</td>
                        <td>abdelazizabde@gmail.com</td>
                        <td>+212672729112</td>
                        <td>Oui</td>
                        <td><a class="file" href=""><img class="icons" src="file.svg" alt="file"></a></td>
                        <td><a class="link-accepted" href=""><img class="icons" src="accepted.svg" alt="accepted"></a></td>
                        <td><a class="link-rejected" href=""><img class="icons" src="rejected.svg" alt="rejected"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Abdelhak</td>
                        <td>Abdelaziz</td>
                        <td>BD2034591</td>
                        <td>abdelazizabde@gmail.com</td>
                        <td>+212672729112</td>
                        <td>Oui</td>
                        <td><a class="file" href=""><img class="icons" src="file.svg" alt="file"></a></td>
                        <td><a class="link-accepted" href=""><img class="icons" src="accepted.svg" alt="accepted"></a></td>
                        <td><a class="link-rejected" href=""><img class="icons" src="rejected.svg" alt="rejected"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Abdelhak</td>
                        <td>Abdelaziz</td>
                        <td>BD2034591</td>
                        <td>abdelazizabde@gmail.com</td>
                        <td>+212672729112</td>
                        <td>Oui</td>
                        <td><a class="file" href=""><img class="icons" src="file.svg" alt="file"></a></td>
                        <td><a class="link-accepted" href=""><img class="icons" src="accepted.svg" alt="accepted"></a></td>
                        <td><a class="link-rejected" href=""><img class="icons" src="rejected.svg" alt="rejected"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </main>



I used display: flex and justify-content: center to main and it works, but when the table is wider than main, the left side starts to disappear and hides behind nav.
I also tried to remove fixed from the nav bar and make everything flex but it caused weird issues, especially since I need the nav bar to be fixed in case of y-overflow

This is because you've set position:fixed on the vertical nav bar, which takes it out of the normal flow. The margin set on main won't respect to it.
One option is to use a flex container and use margin:auto on main instead.
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: start;
}

main{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1rem;
    overflow-x: auto;
    scrollbar-width: thin;
}



:root {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: black;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 15rem;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.navbar-nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-item {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar-item:first-child {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 5rem;
}

.navbar-item:first-child img {
  width: 7rem;
  height: auto;
}

.navbar-item:not(:first-child):hover {
  background-color: rgb(222, 221, 221);
}

.navbar-item:not(:first-child):active {
  background-color: #0f9660;
}

.navbar-item:not(:first-child):active>a {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-item:last-child {
  border: none;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.navbar-item:last-child a:hover {
  background-color: #da413e;
  color: white;
}

.nav-link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar-item svg {
  width: 1rem;
  height: auto;
}

.active {
  background-color: rgb(222, 221, 221);
}

.table thead {
  background-color: #0f9660;
  color: white;
}

.div-table {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.div-table table {
  width: 48rem;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.table th {
  width: 6rem;
  height: 2rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.table td {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.table tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}

.icons {
  width: auto;
  height: 1rem;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
}
<div class=wrapper>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="navbar-item"><img src="../cri.png" alt="Logo of CRI"></li>
      <li class="navbar-item active"><a href="../dashboard/dashboard.html" class="nav-link">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-item"><a href="../search/search.html" class="nav-link">Advanced Search</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-item"><a href="../current/current.html" class="nav-link">Current interns</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-item"><a href="../logs/logs.html" class="nav-link">Read Logs</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Disconnect</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <div class="div-table">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              Nom
            </th>
            <th>
              Prenom
            </th>
            <th>
              CIN
            </th>
            <th>
              Email
            </th>
            <th>
              Numero
            </th>
            <th>
              Etudiant
            </th>
            <th>
              CV
            </th>
            <th>
              Accepter
            </th>
            <th>
              Refuser
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Abdelhak</td>
            <td>Abdelaziz</td>
            <td>BD2034591</td>
            <td>abdelazizabde@gmail.com</td>
            <td>+212672729112</td>
            <td>Oui</td>
            <td>
              <a class="file" href=""><img class="icons" src="file.svg" alt="file"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a class="link-accepted" href=""><img class="icons" src="accepted.svg" alt="accepted"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a class="link-rejected" href=""><img class="icons" src="rejected.svg" alt="rejected"></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Abdelhak</td>
            <td>Abdelaziz</td>
            <td>BD2034591</td>
            <td>abdelazizabde@gmail.com</td>
            <td>+212672729112</td>
            <td>Oui</td>
            <td>
              <a class="file" href=""><img class="icons" src="file.svg" alt="file"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a class="link-accepted" href=""><img class="icons" src="accepted.svg" alt="accepted"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a class="link-rejected" href=""><img class="icons" src="rejected.svg" alt="rejected"></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Abdelhak</td>
            <td>Abdelaziz</td>
            <td>BD2034591</td>
            <td>abdelazizabde@gmail.com</td>
            <td>+212672729112</td>
            <td>Oui</td>
            <td>
              <a class="file" href=""><img class="icons" src="file.svg" alt="file"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a class="link-accepted" href=""><img class="icons" src="accepted.svg" alt="accepted"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a class="link-rejected" href=""><img class="icons" src="rejected.svg" alt="rejected"></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Abdelhak</td>
            <td>Abdelaziz</td>
            <td>BD2034591</td>
            <td>abdelazizabde@gmail.com</td>
            <td>+212672729112</td>
            <td>Oui</td>
            <td>
              <a class="file" href=""><img class="icons" src="file.svg" alt="file"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a class="link-accepted" href=""><img class="icons" src="accepted.svg" alt="accepted"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a class="link-rejected" href=""><img class="icons" src="rejected.svg" alt="rejected"></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Abdelhak</td>
            <td>Abdelaziz</td>
            <td>BD2034591</td>
            <td>abdelazizabde@gmail.com</td>
            <td>+212672729112</td>
            <td>Oui</td>
            <td>
              <a class="file" href=""><img class="icons" src="file.svg" alt="file"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a class="link-accepted" href=""><img class="icons" src="accepted.svg" alt="accepted"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a class="link-rejected" href=""><img class="icons" src="rejected.svg" alt="rejected"></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Abdelhak</td>
            <td>Abdelaziz</td>
            <td>BD2034591</td>
            <td>abdelazizabde@gmail.com</td>
            <td>+212672729112</td>
            <td>Oui</td>
            <td>
              <a class="file" href=""><img class="icons" src="file.svg" alt="file"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a class="link-accepted" href=""><img class="icons" src="accepted.svg" alt="accepted"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a class="link-rejected" href=""><img class="icons" src="rejected.svg" alt="rejected"></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Abdelhak</td>
            <td>Abdelaziz</td>
            <td>BD2034591</td>
            <td>abdelazizabde@gmail.com</td>
            <td>+212672729112</td>
            <td>Oui</td>
            <td>
              <a class="file" href=""><img class="icons" src="file.svg" alt="file"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a class="link-accepted" href=""><img class="icons" src="accepted.svg" alt="accepted"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a class="link-rejected" href=""><img class="icons" src="rejected.svg" alt="rejected"></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>



